# ImportEror: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python

How should I correctly import `MyClass.py` in `SecondClass.py`?

**I've tried to do as follows**

```
from ...ConfigFolder.Config import *
```

**but then for some reason i am getting:**

```
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

**My folder structure:**

```
projectfolder
             |
              - ConfigFolder
                            |-Config.py (inside is MyClass.py)
             |
              - DalFolder
                            |-OtherFold
                                       |-Dal.py (inside SecondClass.py)
             |
              - app.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can import from the directories you've created, you'll need to create an `__init__.py` file in the folder. It can be an empty file.

Comment: you mean where exactly should i put that file?